# Moving from Oracle web toolkit to Apex 4.2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

Suppose I have a procedure like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc IS
var_empno emp.empno%type;
var_ename emp.ename%type;
var_bonus emp.bonus%type;
var_budget number;
var_budget := 100000;

CURSOR EMP_CURSOR IS
select empno, ename, bonus from emp order by empno;

BEGIN
htp.print('EMPLOYEE NUMBER   EMPLOYEE NAME    BONUS');

open EMP_CURSOR;
LOOP
fetch EMP_CURSOR into var_empno, var_ename,  var_bonus;
//------Give employee a extra $1,000 bonus if budget allows-----------.
EXIT when EMP_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;

IF (var_budget >= 1000) then
  var_budget := var_budget - 1000;
  var_bonus := var_bonus + 1000; 
END IF;

//----DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(var_empno || ' ' || var_ename || ' ' || var_bonus);
htp.print(var_empno || ' ' || var_ename || ' ' || var_bonus);
END LOOP;

close EMP_CURSOR;
END;
```

The procedure selects empno, name, and bonus from the emp table ordered by lowest empno.  The cursor loops through and adds $1,000 to the bonus variable if var_budget has the funds for it.  The report uses htp.print.

Of course this is just a simple example and my report html would be formatted better.  We have over 100 procedures like this.  What is the best way to handle logic like this in APEX where a cursor is used and the output is unique for each row.  APEX seems to be good with simple select statements.  But I am unclear how to convert procedures like this for APEX 4.2

Comment: The good news is that you can recycle your ref cursor based stored procedures.  The thing to note however is that a little rework and prep is required, since most Apex native design elements are set up to work with a function or SQL SELECT query output.  Check out my posted response below to see a walk-through of the tasks ahead of you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Adapting Oracle REF CURSOR Data for APEX Report Regions

> The following solution was developed on a demo hosted instance of Oracle Apex at apex.oracle.com;  At the time this was done, the hosted Apex release version was: 4.2.5

Depending on which version of Oracle you are looking at, the implementation of `REF CURSOR` logic has changed in small ways.  I found a good discussion here from Oracle-Base.  The notable changes include:

1. Creation of a `SYS_REFCURSOR` type, which eliminates the need for developers to declare their own custom types independently to have a `REF CURSOR` type to reference in their code.
2. Programming languages/platforms such as **Microsoft ADO** or **Java** have syntax and structures that are equipped to open and iterate over the records stored in a `REF CURSOR`.  This is probably why there are many shops like yours with procedural code in `REF CURSOR` data structures; they're simple and compatible with other programming languages.
3. APEX report region definitions ***work best with a data input defined by a SQL*** **`SELECT`** ***query***.

### Adapting Existing REF CURSOR Based PL/SQL Code from Oracle Web Toolkit

Here is the sample procedure from the OP with comments on initial changes to adapt it for use with an APEX Report Output region.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc (bonus_increase IN number, 
       result_data OUT sys_refcursor) IS

    -- (1) Replace Procedure Declaration to include output REF CURSOR
    -- CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc IS

    -- (2) Remove variable references/placeholders used by procedure 
    --     for data output display reasons.
    -- var_empno emp.empno%type;
    -- var_ename emp.ename%type;
    -- var_bonus emp.bonus%type;
    -- var_budget number;
    -- var_budget := 100000;

    -- (3) A suggested practice to put a tolerance level within a 
    --     constant variable.
    --
    --     Removing literals from the SQL code segments improves 
    --     performance, because it allows the PL/SQL interpreter to 
    --     reuse the execution plans for multiple consecutive runs of 
    --     the cursor query.

    c_var_budget_limit    constant number:= 100000;
    l_var_budget          number;

    CURSOR EMP_CURSOR IS
    select empno, ename, bonus from emp order by empno;

    BEGIN

    -- (4) This task is reserved for APEX to handle in a REPORT REGION 
    --     definition.
    -- htp.print('EMPLOYEE NUMBER   EMPLOYEE NAME    BONUS');

    -- (5) I rewrote the cursor using the IMPLICIT cursor method.

    l_var_budget:= c_var_budget_limit;

    for result_data in EMP_CURSOR

    LOOP
       IF (l_var_budget >= bonus_increase) then
          l_var_budget := l_var_budget - bonus_increase;
          result_data.bonus:= result_data.bonus + bonus_increase;
       END IF;

    END LOOP;

    -- (6) The web toolkit output is no longer necessary.
    //----DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(var_empno || ' ' || var_ename || ' ' 
    -- || var_bonus);
    -- htp.print(var_empno || ' ' || var_ename || ' ' || var_bonus);

    END;
```

The commented sections show how much of the burden for display and output and formatting conventions have been removed. I found a good reference on how to use `REF CURSORS` as encapsulated queries of business logic in an article: [Using Ref Cursors Reference](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php) posted in a reference on "oracle-base.com".

The cleaned up procedure, modeled after this reference looks like:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc_data (result_data OUT sys_refcursor) 
    IS
    BEGIN
    OPEN result_data FOR
       SELECT empno, ename, 0 as bonus
       FROM   emp
       ORDER BY empno ASC;

    END;
```

The calling procedure that opens and loops through the cursor contents looks similar to the OP procedure, in the form of an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
    DECLARE
       l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
       l_empno   emp.empno%TYPE;
       l_ename   emp.ename%TYPE;
       l_bonus   number;

       c_var_budget_limit    constant number:= 100000;
       c_bonus_increase      constant number:= 1000;
       l_var_budget          number;

    BEGIN
       my_proc_data (result_data => l_cursor);
       l_var_budget := c_var_budget_limit;
        
    LOOP 
       FETCH l_cursor
       INTO  l_empno, l_ename, l_bonus;

       IF (l_var_budget >= c_bonus_increase) then
          l_var_budget := l_var_budget - c_bonus_increase;
          l_bonus:= l_bonus + c_bonus_increase;

          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(l_empno) || ' | ' || l_ename || 
             ' | ' || to_char(l_bonus));

       END IF;

    EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE l_cursor;
    END;
```

The result output:

```
    7369 | SMITH | 1000
    7499 | ALLEN | 1000
    7521 | WARD | 1000
    7566 | JONES | 1000
    7654 | MARTIN | 1000
    7698 | BLAKE | 1000
    7782 | CLARK | 1000
    7788 | SCOTT | 1000
    7839 | KING | 1000
    7844 | TURNER | 1000
    7876 | ADAMS | 1000
    7900 | JAMES | 1000
    7902 | FORD | 1000
    7934 | MILLER | 1000
    7934 | MILLER | 2000

    Statement processed.
```

This isn't the ending solution, remember, the data needs to be fed to APEX in the form of a `SELECT` statement.

### Using Oracle PL/SQL Collections to Deliver `REF CURSOR` Data Through Apex Report Regions

Some additional changes to further prepare the original sample procedure for use with an Apex page region report:

1. Added two new SQL object types: `EMPLOYEE_RECORD_TYPE` and `EMP_OUTPUT_TABLE_TYPE`.
2. Changed to PL/SQL `FUNCTION` object type instead of `PROCEDURE` object type.
3. Changed output data type to `NESTED TABLE` collection type. (This allows us to QUERY the output data stored in this collection using direct SQL).
4. The separated code for the `REF CURSOR` and the report-output query were combined.
5. Converted the Anonymous PL/SQL block used in testing the first part into a `FUNCTION` object.
6. Changed (reduced) the MAX BUDGET value from OP so that we can see the looping logic at work (i.e., running out of budget money to award bonuses to employees)

Here's the revised code:

**SQL Collection and Object Type Definitions (DDL)**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE employee_record_type AS object (
       empno   number,
       ename   varchar2(10),
       bonus   number
    );

    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_output_table_type IS TABLE OF
       employee_record_type;
```

**New PL/SQL Function Definition (Containing REF CURSOR)**

```
    create or replace FUNCTION my_bonuses RETURN
       emp_output_table_type IS

    -- table collection type declared and initialized here:
       l_output  emp_output_table_type:= emp_output_table_type();
       l_row_index   pls_integer:= 0;  

       c_var_budget_limit    constant number:= 100000;
       c_bonus_increase      constant number:= 1000;
       l_var_budget          number;

       cursor l_cursor is
          select empno, ename, 0 as bonus
          from   emp
       order by empno ASC;

    BEGIN
       l_var_budget := c_var_budget_limit;

    FOR i in l_cursor
       LOOP
          l_row_index := l_row_index + 1;
          l_output.extend;

          l_output(l_row_index):= employee_record_type(i.empno,
             i.ename, i.bonus);

    IF (l_var_budget >= c_bonus_increase) then
       l_var_budget := l_var_budget - c_bonus_increase;
       l_output(l_row_index).bonus:= l_output(l_row_index).bonus
           + c_bonus_increase;

    END IF;

    END LOOP;
    RETURN l_output;
    END;
```

**Function MY_BONUSES When Queried from SQL Client**

[image: Test Query of New Function with Nested Table Collection Output]

This is the SQL that will be referenced in the Apex page report definition as in the "Region Source" section of the Region Definition configuration page.

**Comparison: Source Table Data vs. REF CURSOR query results**

[image: Results From Collection Data Type Output]

### Some Closing Comments and Discussion

This example leaves room for lots of optimizations given the leaps in the product versions of the RDBMS between Oracle 9i, up to and including 11g and 12c.  Some side-thoughts for consideration:

1. Use of bulk-binding operations and methods when loading data from ref-cursors to Oracle collection types.
2. Additional modularization.  You can see the components of the OP procedure `my_proc` moved around a little during the development of this solution.  Your conversion effort may benefit from better organization using packages and separation of processes (where it makes sense).
3. Read up on the documentation on Oracle PL/SQL collections.  You will learn a few important distinctions:
   a. Some collection types can be queried directly with SQL.
   b. Composite data types defined in PL/SQL vs at the schema level each have their own limitations...

In general, choose wisely, or just stick with this example as it should get you most of the way towards converting an existing library of PL/SQL code with `REF CURSOR` driven parameters/outputs.

Onward!

Comment: The "create type employee_record_type" part makes me sad.  If that is the only way to do it, I will have to create over 100 of these.  Any time we modify the column order we have have to remember to find the related "type".  I am thinking I would rather use a temp table or more like an output table.  I don't know, I see I would still have to call a procedure.  I understand Apex works well with SELECTS    but is it possible to call a procedure and than do a select in APEX?  That way I could have the proc run, insert rows to a table and do the select.  Only 3 or 4 users, so people running report

Comment: ..at the same time is not going to happen.  These reports are dashboard like helper reports.  Not critical business process stuff.  This data is more like the data warehouse and not the online store OLTP db.

Comment: That may be possible. Apex has a useful session and user based object called `APEX_COLLECTIONS` it is a table with multiple generic varchar and numeric typed columns... c01, c02, c03, n01, n02, n03, etc.  I have seen other developers use this object as a holding bucket for multiple record outputs.  With a little tweaking, you can test this by populating this collections object with the procedure call, then modify the select with column aliases to generate the output.  The generic name suggests this persistent object is reusable.  May some of this discussion open up more options for you!